# How to create a dependent pick list using custom object in visual force?

Tags: salesforce

I need to create a dependent picklist using custom object in Visualforce. My requirement is if I create an object country this is master detail, then state is child & city also. Then I need to show contact details of that particular city.

Answer (score 0):

Firt you have to create to custom field .
Click field dependency[image: Click field depend]

Then new controller field and dependent [image]

So that you could add the depent